# Who were you there with OR with there

Tags: word-order

which is correct:

> 1) Who were you there with?
>
> 2) Who were you with there?

The second example:

> 1) Who will I come in the evening with?
>
> 2) Who will I come with in the evening?

And the third one:

> 1) Who will the window have been broken by the evening by?
>
> 2) Who will the window have been broken by by the evening?

Comment: Will you please provide explanation about what is the purpose of the question? Should we do the homework for you? Did you do any research for it? What is your understanding? What are your findings?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer for all three examples which range from correct but not particularly idiomatic to completely and utterly incorrect. I think you may be looking for a rule that does not exist.

> 1) Who were you there with?

I would use this phrase. It is colloquially correct and commonly used in everyday speech. Although to be *completely* correct you should really ask "*with whom did you go there?*"

> 2) Who were you with there?

This doesn't scan correctly. It would probably be understood but it just sounds awkward. In a conversation where you have already established where "there" is, you could simply say "*Who were you with?*"

This is probably the best of your three examples as what I believe you are trying to ascertain is the structure of the sentence. As the question is "*who*" the *focus* of the question should really be about the person and not the location.

---

> 1) Who will I come in the evening with?

This time your first example is the one that is not idiomatic. It is just a bit awkward. But see my response to your next example.

> 2) Who will I come with in the evening?

This is *phrased* correctly but doesn't make sense because you are *asking* who you *will* come with. How can someone else know who you *will* bring? You should say "*Who **shall** I come with in the evening?*"

---

> 1) Who will the window have been broken by the evening by?
>
> 2) Who will the window have been broken by by the evening?

*Neither* of these make any sense. For a start, why would anyone ask who *will* break a window in the future? I would refer to my response to your other two examples to answer your question.

Comment: 1) But if I haven't established it or I want to repeat it again?
But in this example you offer to put "place" before the "preposition"? This is the only correct way, yes?
2) It may be not lke asking who I should take with myself, but just who will be come with by me. 
Here you offer to put firstly "time" and only then "preposition"? Like, it can be conversely and both will be acceptable but time-preposition will be better?

3) The context isn't important. I am intersted in the ordering of "by" and "by the evening. It will be time-preposition? By the evening by?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko 1)If you want to repeat it then use the first example that I stated was most common. 2) Then ask "*Who will come with me?*", not "*who will I come with*", as I explained that makes no sense, probably not in any language 3) Context is *always* important. Context is *king*. Rules of any language have exceptions. If you want to understand the *ordering* then consider example 1 - the second option in that example sounds awkward because the ordering makes the focus of the question the location when you are using "*who*" so it really ought to be about the person you went with.

Comment: 2) we can change the sentence for "Who will he be noticed in the evening with"? Or "who he will be noticed with in the evening?" if you don't like the original one.
Look, can we say it easier that we always have to put the preposition at the end of the sentence.
1) 1) Who were you there with?
2) Who will he be noticed in the evening with?
3) Who of you had the person been killed by the moment he came by?
Correct?
In all three sentences the prepositions have the last place in the sentence.

Comment: @AstralBee: You said: **You should say "Who shall I come with in the evening?"** However, the dictionary (https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shall) states: _" In practice, however, shall and will are today used more or less interchangeably in statements [...] The interchangeable use of shall and will is now part of standard British and US English"_ Now which is the "truth"? I ask as non-native English speaker, and experience shows a very blurry difference between "shall" and "will". +1, anyway ;)